# Как конвертировать тип данных?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день!
У меня есть список новостей, для которого создан адаптер

```
 public class NewsFeedRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsFeedRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {


private List<News> mItems;
private Context mContext;
private NewsFeedRecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;

public NewsFeedRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<News> items) {
    mItems = items;
    mContext = context;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
   return position;
```

^
Здесь прописан метод получения позиции 1 новости, который возвращает значение в формате long.

Еще у меня есть отдельный класс News, шаблон все данных:

```
public class News extends RealmObject {

@SerializedName("id")
@PrimaryKey
private long mId;

public long getId() {
    return mId;
}

public void setId(long mId) {
    this.mId = mId;
}
```

^ Здесь прописано id 1 новости;

А теперь уважаемые знатоки вопрос! :)
Как мне в отдельном фрагменте с подробной информацией этой самой 1 новости прописать правильно intent.
Нужно, чтобы он из адаптера брал позицию и сохранял id из класса News.

Вот на что способен мой пытливый ум:

```
mAdapter = new NewsFeedRecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), strings);
    mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener((view, position) -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailNewsActivity.class);
        News news = (News) mAdapter.getItemId(position);
        intent.putExtra("id", news.getId());
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    });
```

но у меня происходит конфликт 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что делать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вам надо достать id новости, то по вашему коду надо выполнить следующее

```
intent.putExtra("id", strings.get(position).getId());
```

Answer (score 4):

Метод `getItemId`, как подсказывает его название, возвращает ид элемента по переданной позиции. Соответственно пытаться привести тип `long` в `News` не стоит.

Что бы получить именно объект `News`, то добавьте в ваш адаптер метод

```
public Message getItem(int position) {
    return mItems.get(position);
}
```

и используйте его.

Если вам нужен просто ид новости, то достаточно переопределить метод `getItemId(int position)` следующим образом.

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
   return mItem.get(position).getId();
}
```

Если этого не сделать, то будет возвращаться неправильный ид новости, в результате чего будет неправильно отображена информация

Answer (score 2):

Метод `mAdapter.getItemId(position)` возвращает **ID новости**, а не сам объект новости (**поле экземпляра вместо целого экземпляра**).
Вам нужно либо вызывать конструктор класса News либо получать объект класса News из некоей коллекции по полученному ID.

UPD: Либо использовать полученные данные напрямую, как в ответе выше:

```
intent.putExtra("id", mAdapter.getItemId(position));
```